# How to add the Procedural Nebula shader to a new blend file

Tags: procedural

I found a procedural nebular shader online https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pB1DS7ISoy0

I am new to blender I don't see this shader when I start 2.9, is this an addon, or how do i create the shader in a my current blend file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the link on your question:

[image]

Download the blend file and open it from blender.

The rest of the "instructions" to use it are on the video

To use it in your own project you can copy the assets to this project or you can append the material from the downloaded file to an existing project.